# JS Bin to Sublime Text : popover disabled

Tags: html, ide, jsbin

This is the code I've been testing in JS Bin to create popovers for my website:

http://jsbin.com/akutis/5/edit

(be sure to click on "run with JS" for it to work)

When I import the code into my Sublime Text editor, I create a popover.js file where I paste the jquery code from JS Bin.

Then I just add in the head the following link to my own jquery file:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!--just adding the following line-->
<script src="popover.js"></script>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
```

However, when I then run the files locally, the popovers don't work. Not sure what is causing this problem. Is there a translation issue (JS Bin --> local) I am not addressing? How can the code not work anymore if I am simply copying and pasting?

Tanks so much for your help.

Comment: are you sure you've included popover.js? Do you get an error message in the javascript console?

Comment: Yes I'm sure I've included it, and no error message...